# How to default my python to another python version

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a big headache dealing with python versions. I couldn't do `pip install xlwt` because it was complaining to me about SSL certification problem. So then I installed python 2.7.16 and installed xlwt and got `Requirement already satisfied: xlwt in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.3.0)`

However then when I run `python code.py` I keep getting `ImportError: No module named xlwt` although I just did `pip install xlwt`

what should I do?

Comment: pip list also tells me that I have ```xlwt       1.3.0```

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to make sure your `pip` refers to the correct python version is to call it explicitly from the python version you intend to use, e.g.

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip install some-package
```

If it complains that the pip module is missing, you can install it via:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
/usr/bin/python2.7 get-pip.py
```

You can replace `/usr/bin/python2.7` with whatever version you want to use.